# How to get the height of an element after you scroll past it?

Tags: javascript, html, css

In the code snippet below when you click on the `This is four` text on the header it will scroll down to the 4th section. Before it scrolls down the header is some height `x` and after you scroll the header becomes sticky and increases in height.

How can I get the height of the header after it becomes sticky? The reason I want to do this is that the scrolling doesn't go exactly at the top of each section. The section keeps being cut off I think it's due to the sticky header height that keeps changing. So I want to scroll the window the height of the sticky header so the sections line up properly.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 28px;
}

#navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  padding: 25px 16px;
}

#navbar a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
  margin-right: 15px;
}

.content {
  padding: 16px;
}

.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 100;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16);
}

.common {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 200px 10px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="header">
    <p>Scroll down to see the sticky effect.</p>
  </div>

  <div id="navbar">
    <a onclick="headerClick(this); return false;" href="#">This is One</a>
    <a onclick="headerClick(this); return false;" href="#">This is Two</a>
    <a onclick="headerClick(this); return false;" href="#">This is Three</a>
    <a onclick="headerClick(this); return false;" href="#">This is Four</a>
  </div>

  <div class="content">
    <div class="common" id="One">This is the first</div>
    <div class="common" id="Two">Two</div>
    <div class="common" id="Three">Three</div>
    <div class="common" id="Four">Four</div>
    <div class="common" id="Five">Five</div>
    <div class="common">Filler div to make scrolling longer</div>
    <div class="common">Filler div to make scrolling longer</div>
    <div class="common">Filler div to make scrolling longer</div>
  </div>

  <script>
    window.onscroll = function() {
      myFunction()
    };

    var navbar = document.getElementById("navbar");
    var sticky = navbar.offsetTop;

    function myFunction() {
      if (window.pageYOffset >= sticky) {
        navbar.classList.add("sticky")
        document.getElementById("navbar").style.padding = "40px 16px";
      } else {
        navbar.classList.remove("sticky");
        document.getElementById("navbar").style.padding = "25px 16px";
      }
    }

    function headerClick(elem) {
      if (elem.innerHTML === 'This is One') {
        document.getElementById("One").scrollIntoView();
      }
      if (elem.innerHTML === 'This is Two') {
        document.getElementById("Two").scrollIntoView();
      }
      if (elem.innerHTML === 'This is Three') {
        document.getElementById("Three").scrollIntoView();
      }
      if (elem.innerHTML === 'This is Four') {
        document.getElementById("Four").scrollIntoView();
      }
    }
  </script>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Problem

The `scrollIntoView` function you're using is working as intended. However, because you're scrolling only until the **top** of the element, the top portion is hidden by the `position: fixed` sticky navbar. What can we do to solve this? Adjust the scroll position after using `scrollIntoView`.

---

### Workaround

You asked how to get the height of an element after you scroll past it. You wanted to get the height of the element so that you can adjust the scroll position after using `scrollIntoView`. However, this isn't necessary. Simply add the class (or the inline style) that increases the height of the `navbar`, then measure its height, then revert the changes you've made (I did this on `var stickyHeight = ...`).

After you have the height of the sticky element, you can readjust the position of scroll after using `scrollIntoView` (by subtracting the navbar sticky height from the position after `scrollIntoView` happens). However, there are still problems: when you click on a header when the navbar isn't fixed yet **and** the first element.

Why is clicking on a header when the navbar isn't fixed yet a problem? This is because before adjusting the navbar to `position: fixed`, it's still in the normal flow of the document and its height changes the document's height. When it is fixed, it's taken out of the normal document flow and its height is removed from the document's height. This means that we have to readjust the subtraction formula when this happens. I have done it in the following solution.

Why is the first element a problem? Well, this is mainly due to the design you want. You simply can't show the very top of the element while the bar is stickied. Try scrolling very slowly manually to see what I mean.

---

### Solution

Here's a working solution. Do try running it.

```js
window.onscroll = function() {
  myFunction()
};

var navbar = document.getElementById("navbar");
var sticky = navbar.offsetTop;
// Getting sticky and nonStickyHeight for scroll readjustments
var nonStickyHeight = navbar.scrollHeight
var stickyHeight = (() => {
  navbar.style.padding = "40px 16px" // Or add the class that adds padding
  let result = navbar.scrollHeight
  navbar.style.padding = '' // Or remove the class that adds padding
  return result
})()

function myFunction() {
  if (window.pageYOffset >= sticky) {
    navbar.classList.add("sticky")
    document.getElementById("navbar").style.padding = "40px 16px";
  } else {
    navbar.classList.remove("sticky");
    document.getElementById("navbar").style.padding = "25px 16px";
  }
}

function headerClick(elem) {
  let firstElementClicked = false
  let navbarIsSticky = false
  
  // Check if navbar is stickied when the headings are clicked
  if (navbar.scrollHeight === stickyHeight) navbarIsSticky = true
  
  if (elem.innerHTML === 'This is One') {
    document.getElementById("One").scrollIntoView();
    firstElementClicked = true
  }
  if (elem.innerHTML === 'This is Two') {
    document.getElementById("Two").scrollIntoView();
  }
  if (elem.innerHTML === 'This is Three') {
    document.getElementById("Three").scrollIntoView();
  }
  if (elem.innerHTML === 'This is Four') {
    document.getElementById("Four").scrollIntoView();
  }
  
  // If the navbar is stickied and it's not the first element, just subtract the stickyHeight from the scroll position
  if (!firstElementClicked && navbarIsSticky) window.scroll(window.pageXOffset, window.pageYOffset - stickyHeight - 5)
  
  else if (firstElementClicked && !navbarIsSticky)
    window.scroll(window.pageXOffset, window.pageYOffset - nonStickyHeight)
  
  // If the navbar is not stickied, you have to take account the nonStickyHeight that will be removed from the document's height when the navbar is stickied
  else if (!navbarIsSticky) window.scroll(window.pageXOffset, window.pageYOffset - nonStickyHeight - stickyHeight - 5)
}
```

```css
* {
  /*scroll-behavior: smooth;*/
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 28px;
}

#navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  padding: 25px 16px;
}

#navbar a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
  margin-right: 15px;
}

.content {
  padding: 16px;
}

.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 100;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16);
}

.common {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 200px 10px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="header">
    <p>Scroll down to see the sticky effect.</p>
  </div>

  <div id="navbar">
    <a onclick="headerClick(this); return false;" href="#">This is One</a>
    <a onclick="headerClick(this); return false;" href="#">This is Two</a>
    <a onclick="headerClick(this); return false;" href="#">This is Three</a>
    <a onclick="headerClick(this); return false;" href="#">This is Four</a>
  </div>

  <div class="content">
    <div class="common" id="One">This is the first</div>
    <div class="common" id="Two">Two</div>
    <div class="common" id="Three">Three</div>
    <div class="common" id="Four">Four</div>
    <div class="common" id="Five">Five</div>
    <div class="common">Filler div to make scrolling longer</div>
    <div class="common">Filler div to make scrolling longer</div>
    <div class="common">Filler div to make scrolling longer</div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: This is perfect! This is exactly what I was trying next to determine if it's sticky or not based on that boolean. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Quick question what is the purpose of the `firstElementClicked` variable? When I click on the fourth tab in the header it scrolls down to the fourth section. Then when you click on the first tab it cuts off the first section a bit.

Comment: @CapturedTree I've updated my code in regard to the `firstElementClicked` variable. The variable is used to determine whether it is the first element that is being clicked. Why do we need to detect this? Because your design does not allow the first box to show fully **and** the navbar to be stickied. Because of this, I opted to sticky the navbar, but at the cost of some small portion of the first box to be covered.

Answer (score 0):

The content gets cut because it ends up behind the navbar, so you could for example add extra padding to the top of the `.content` so that when it gets behind the navbar it just expands.

Feel free to change the values as it might be a bit jittery, but seems to have the effect you're looking for.

```js
window.onscroll = function() {
  myFunction();
};

var navbar = document.getElementById("navbar");
var sticky = navbar.offsetTop;

function myFunction() {
  if (window.pageYOffset >= sticky) {
    navbar.classList.add("sticky");
    document.getElementById("navbar").style.padding = "40px 16px";
    document.querySelector(".content").style.paddingTop = "116px";
  } else {
    navbar.classList.remove("sticky");
    document.querySelector(".content").style.paddingTop = "16px";
    document.getElementById("navbar").style.padding = "25px 16px";
  }
}

function headerClick(elem) {
  if (elem.innerHTML === "This is One") {
    document.getElementById("One").scrollIntoView();
  }
  if (elem.innerHTML === "This is Two") {
    document.getElementById("Two").scrollIntoView();
  }
  if (elem.innerHTML === "This is Three") {
    document.getElementById("Three").scrollIntoView();
  }
  if (elem.innerHTML === "This is Four") {
    document.getElementById("Four").scrollIntoView();
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 28px;
}

#navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  padding: 25px 16px;
}

#navbar a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
  margin-right: 15px;
}

.content {
  padding: 16px;
}

.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 100;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16);
}

.common {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 200px 10px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <p>Scroll down to see the sticky effect.</p>
</div>

<div id="navbar">
  <a onclick="headerClick(this); return false;" href="#">This is One</a>
  <a onclick="headerClick(this); return false;" href="#">This is Two</a>
  <a onclick="headerClick(this); return false;" href="#">This is Three</a>
  <a onclick="headerClick(this); return false;" href="#">This is Four</a>
</div>

<div class="content">
  <div class="common" id="One">This is the first</div>
  <div class="common" id="Two">Two</div>
  <div class="common" id="Three">Three</div>
  <div class="common" id="Four">Four</div>
  <div class="common" id="Five">Five</div>
  <div class="common">Filler div to make scrolling longer</div>
  <div class="common">Filler div to make scrolling longer</div>
  <div class="common">Filler div to make scrolling longer</div>
</div>
```